# How to insert sum of col grouped by another col in new col

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to multiply 2 columns "qty*price_dl" of table and but the value in new column "total1" in the same table and this work with me without problems

after that trying to get sum of "total1" column grouped by "seq" column and but the values in "total2" column in the same table
I'm stuck in process of summation it doesn't work with me
this is the code:

```
<?php
require_once("dbconfig.php");
$q=mysql_query('select * from sale_menu')
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>qty</th>
    <th>price_dl</th>
    <th>total1</th>

</tr><tr>";
while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rw['seq']; ?>" name="seq[]" ></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $rw['qty']; ?></b></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $rw['price_dl']; ?></b></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $rw['total1']; ?></b></td>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $seq=$_POST['seq'];
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        $impid=implode(", ",$seq);
        $qdel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sale_menu WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qdel)){
            $qty=$row['qty'];
            $price_dl=$row['price_dl'];
            $qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total1=qty*price_dl WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
            $qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total2=sum(total1) WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
        }
    }
    ?>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Checked" id="submit" >Move</button>
```

this is where I stuck:

```
$qdel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sale_menu WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
$qdel=mysql_query("select sum(total1) as total from sale_menu group by seq");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qdel)){
$total =  $row['total'];
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total1=qty*price_dl WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total2= $total WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
```

Comment: We stopped using this API about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant put total1 as column here because you need to make query inside query and there is two ways to do it

The first it to do nested query like this

```
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total2= (select sum(total1) as total from table_name) WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
```

The second is way much easier just make another query before this query and store the value of sum(total1) inside a variable then you can use the variable in this query for example

```
$q=mysql_query('select sum(total1) as total from table_name')
while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

   $total =  $rw['total'];
 }
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total2= $total WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: first solution doen't work
but second work partially it get the sum of one seq value

`$qdel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sale_menu WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
$qdel=mysql_query("select sum(total1) as total from sale_menu group by seq ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qdel)){
$total =  $row['total'];
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total1=qty*price_dl WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");
$qdel=mysql_query("UPDATE sale_menu set total2= $total WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")");`

all values of total2 column is the sum value where seq=2 only why it doesn't work with other seq number 3,4,5..ets.?

Comment: I just update the question above with new code in the last lines so you can read it clearly there

Comment: nooo not everything okay if you know why it get the sum of only first seq values where seq=2 and update whole total2 col with this value while there is seq=3 and seq=4 .. etc. so I need to make each group of seq number get it's summation
if you can help me too thanks a lot

Comment: you can use this trick to debug your code take the hole query text and execute it inside phpmyadmin or other then you can know what the query do 
for example 
echo "UPDATE sale_menu set total2= $total WHERE seq IN(".$impid.")" ;
then it will print for you this code inside your html page take the generated code and execute it at less you will see the values then you can know whats the wrong with it 
Good luck